# Django: How to include both limited access, and models in same view?

Tags: python, django

I have a django music project with a site called Add-Album. I want only registered users to upload abums.

When I added the limited access in views.py, I had to change the view from class-view to function-view. But then i got a problem. Everything worked fine, without the template. No forms showed up in the template(when it was class-view the showed up).

My question is how can I include both limited access, and the models in same view?

```
#Views.py
# ....
# My model and fields
#    model = Album
#    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

# before this was a class view with the model and fields
def AlbumCreate(request):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('{}?next={}'.format(settings.LOGIN_URL, request.path))
    return render(request, 'Music/album_form.html')


class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']


class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Music:Music')

#  ....


#models
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    album_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='albumlogo/')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist

#urls.py

#...
url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),
url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),
url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate, name='album-add'),
#...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into create views https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

and then add a permission required mix in to it

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class AlbumCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Album
    form_class = your_form_class
    template_name = "Music/album_form.html"
    permission_required = 'album.create_album'
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Btw I didn't have to whrite form_class = UserForm, instead I wrote fields = ['artist', 'album_title', 'genre', 'album_logo']

Comment: you're welcome! Form classes can be used to create customisable forms if he auto generated forms didnt meat your requirements